Commands run when sourcing a csh script unable to find files and directories that clearly exist
I'm trying to replace a Perl script my team uses with a Python script wrapped in a Shell (csh) script. The usual order of execution is : user sources the .csh file with certain arguments -> .csh file has the whole python code inlined, which it writes to a temporary .py file -> .csh script executes the temporary python file and passes all the user given arguments to it -> python file does its thing, and creates a new temporary .csh file that the main .csh script then sources. Apologies for the unconventional setup, this was the best solution I could find to meet the team's requirement of running everything in the parent shell (tcsh) to have the changes persist between runs.
Most commands that were run this way from the temporary .csh file had no issues, but when I try to grep the log file generated by a previously run command, I get an error saying, "No such file or directory". I'm certain the log file has been successfully created in the location I specified, and that there's no issues in the grep command itself as copy pasting the command in the shell afterwards worked without issues. I also tried using ls to list out the files in the specified file's directory which also throws the same "No such file or directory", leading me to believe the temporary .csh file for some reason is not able to access the given directory.
I looked around for people facing similar issues and tried all of the common fixes suggested, including chmod-ing the newly generated .csh file and using dos2unix on all the temporary files.
Here's a simplified version of the shell wrapper script + in-lined python code, I've removed a good chunk of the python script not relevant to the question (original is 500+ lines):
#!/usr/local/bin/tcsh

set sourced=($_)
if ("$sourced" != "") then
    if $sourced[1] == "source" then
        set script_dir = `pwd`/`dirname $sourced[2]`
        setenv DV_DIR "$script_dir/.."
    endif
else
    set script_dir = `pwd`/`dirname $0`
    setenv DV_DIR "$script_dir/.."
endif

set prog_name = "run_v2"
alias python /home/xxxxxxxx/pyinstall/python3

set temp_py_file  = "$DV_DIR/scripts/temp_$prog_name.py"
set command_file  = "$DV_DIR/scripts/temp_$prog_name.csh"
set temp_tcl_file = "$DV_DIR/scripts/temp_$prog_name.tcl"

cat << EOF > $temp_py_file
#!/home/xxxxxxxx/pyinstall/pyenv/shims python3

import os
import sys
import argparse


def main():
    <parser stuff>

    <script configuration>

    command_list = [
        '#!/usr/local/bin tcsh',
        ]

    <misc stuff>

    if compile:
        cmd_extend_list = run_compile(config_dict, dv_dir, compile_dir, x_prop, coverage, local, config)
        command_list.extend(cmd_extend_list)

    command_file_path = os.path.join(dv_dir,'scripts','temp_run_v2.csh')
    with open(command_file_path, "w") as f:
        for command in command_list: 
            f.write(f"{command}\n")
    
    return


def run_compile(config_dict,dv_dir,compile_dir,x_prop,coverage,local,config):
    
    <building the compile_cmd using user inputs>

    if not os.path.exists(compile_dir):
        os.makedirs(compile_dir)

    command_list = [
        f'printf "Info    : Compile Directory = {compile_dir}' + r'\n\n"',
        f'printf "Info    : Compile Command   = {compile_cmd}' + r'\n\n"',
        f'printf "******* Starting Design and TB compile *******' + r'\n\n"',
        compile_cmd,
        f'printf "' + r'\n"',
        f'printf "******** Exiting Design and TB compile *******' + r'\n\n"',
        ]

    cmd_extend_list = check_result(log_path)
    command_list.extend(cmd_extend_list)

    return command_list


def check_result(log_path):
    command_list = [
        f'set errors_found=\`grep "\*E" "{log_path}"\`',
        f'if ("\$#errors_found" != 0) then',
        f'    printf "Info    : Compilation failed.' + r'\n"',
        f'    printf "Error   : Check the compile log for errors - {log_path}' + r'\n\n"',
        f'    exit 1',
        f'else',
        f'    printf "Info    : Compilation successful.' + r'\n\n"',
        f'endif',
        ''
    ]

    return command_list


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
EOF

dos2unix $temp_py_file
python $temp_py_file $argv
set py_status = $status
if ($py_status != 0) then
    printf "\nError   : $prog_name exited with the error code $py_status.\n\n"
    exit 1
endif
rm -f $temp_py_file

if ( -e $command_file ) then
    dos2unix $command_file
    chmod 777 $command_file
    source $command_file
    set prog_name = "run_v2"
    set command_file  = "$DV_DIR/scripts/temp_$prog_name.csh"
    rm -f $command_file
else
    printf "\nError: Command file $command_file was not created. Check Python script for issues.\n\n"
endif

if ( -e $temp_tcl_file ) then
    set temp_tcl_file = "$DV_DIR/scripts/temp_$prog_name.tcl"
    rm -f $temp_tcl_file
endif

And here the temporary .csh file this would create:
#!/usr/local/bin tcsh
printf "Info    : Compile Directory = <compile_dir>"
printf "Info    : Compile Command   = <compile_cmd ... -l <log path>>" 
printf "******* Starting Design and TB compile *******\n\n"
<compile_cmd>
printf "\n"
printf "******** Exiting Design and TB compile *******\n\n"
set errors_found=`grep "\*E" "<log path>"`
if ("$#errors_found" != 0) then
    printf "Info    : Compilation failed.\n"
    printf "Error   : Check the compile log for errors - <log path>\n\n"
    exit 1
else
    printf "Info    : Compilation successful.\n\n"
endif

The output in shell:
TOOL:   xrun(64)        22.09-s006: Started on Nov 02, 2024 at 15:55:31 IST
xrun: *E,FILEMIS: Cannot find the provided file /xxxx/xxxx/xxxx.
TOOL:   xrun(64)        22.09-s006: Exiting on Nov 02, 2024 at 15:55:32 IST  (total: 00:00:01)

******** Exiting Design and TB compile *******

grep: <log path>: No such file or directory
Info    : Compilation successful.

Copy pasting the same grep command, I get:
grep "\*E" "<log path>"
xrun: *E,FILEMIS: Cannot find the provided file /xxxx/xxxx/xxxx.

Would really appreciate any help here, as I'm completely lost as to what might be going wrong.

Is there a reason you want to use a shell which sane people abandoned 25+ years ago?

As an aside, #!/usr/local/bin tcsh  with a space is definitely an error.

@tripleee I just joined the company, and from what I can gather, peps in the chip design industry take their sweet time moving over to newer alternatives (the Perl script I'm trying to replace has been here for almost a decade and is pretty flawed). Think I forgot to put the / there while editing the code here, issue persists without that too though.

Python doesn't care about DOS line endings but there's hardly any way your script could be adding them (unless perhaps you need to run dos2unix on the script itself; but then there'd be other errors too).

Whatever you are hoping to accomplish, chmod 777 is wrong and dangerous. You will want to revert to sane permissions ASAP (for your use case, probably chmod 755).

I'm not sure I understand why this complex maze of scripts is necessary. If you need Python to be able to change things in your current shell's environment, the usual solution to that is eval \python script which prints some shell commands` `
